# Adding php code to a url link

Tags: php

What php code should I add to the **NEXT ARTICLE** url link below, that will cause the next article to be echoed back subsequently?

I intend to echo back one article after another sequentially.

Thank you!

(form.php)

```
<form action="process.php" method="get">
    Group:
    <select name="group">
        <option value="group1">Group1</option>
        <option value="group2">Group2</option>
    </select>

    Chapter:
    <input type="text" name="chapter">

    Article:
    <input type="text" name="article">

    <input type="submit" value="Go to Article">    

</form>
```

(process.php)

```
<?php

session_start();

$laws=array(
       "group1"=>array(
                      "1"=>array(
                                "1"=>"This is article (1) in chapter (1) of (group1)",
                                "2"=>"This is article (2) in chapter (1) of (group1)",
                                "3"=>"This is article (3) in chapter (1) of (group1)",
                                ),
                      "2"=>array(
                                "1"=>"This is article (1) in chapter (2) of (group1)",
                                "2"=>"This is article (2) in chapter (2) of (group1)",
                                "3"=>"This is article (3) in chapter (2) of (group1)",
                                ),
                       ),
       "group2"=>array(
                      "1"=>array(
                                "1"=>"This is article (1) in chapter (1) of (group2)",
                                "2"=>"This is article (2) in chapter (1) of (group2)",
                                "3"=>"This is article (3) in chapter (1) of (group2)",
                                ),
                      "2"=>array(
                                "1"=>"This is article (1) in chapter (2) of (group2)",
                                "2"=>"This is article (2) in chapter (2) of (group2)",
                                "3"=>"This is article (3) in chapter (2) of (group2)",
                                ),

       )
       );

$grp= $_GET['group'];
$chap = $_GET['chapter'];
$art = $_GET['article'];

if(isset($laws[$grp]) && isset($laws[$grp][$chap]) && isset($laws[$grp][$chap][$art])){
$_SESSION['group'] = $grp;
$_SESSION['chapter'] = $chap;
$_SESSION['article'] = $art;    
}else{
$_SESSION['group'] = 'group1';
$_SESSION['chapter'] = '1';
$_SESSION['article'] = '1';   
}

$group = $_SESSION['group'];
$chapter = $_SESSION['chapter'];
$article = $_SESSION['article'];


echo $laws[$group][$chapter][$article]; // ALL NEXT ARTICLES TO BE ECHOED HERE!!!!!

?>

<a href="process.php" style="text-decoration: none;">NEXT ARTICLE</a>
```

Comment: `$_SESSION['article' = $_GET['article']];` Good luck assigning that.

Comment: How do you determine what the next article is?

Comment: @Jan-Henk: `$_SESSION['nextarticle' = $_GET['nextarticle']];` obviously.

Comment: The syntax of that snippet is wrong ...

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear what the next article is, and you have what appears to be a error (see my comments)

I've updated your code so that the link will load an article (but perhaps its not the next article).  perhaps this will at least help you on your way to finding the answer...

```
    <?php

    // $_GET['group'] receives a string
    // $_GET['chapter'] receives a number
    // $_GET['article'] receives a number


    $_SESSION['group'] = $_GET['group'];
    $_SESSION['chapter'] = $_GET['chapter'];

        // this line here doesn't really make sense....
        //$_SESSION['article' = $_GET['article']];  
        //so perhaps you mean:
        $_SESSION['article'] = $_GET['article'];  

        $group = $_SESSION['group'];
        $chapter = $_SESSION['chapter'];
        $article = $_SESSION['article'];


        echo $group . " " . $chapter . " " . $article . "<br/>";

        $group_num = preg_replace("[^0-9]","",$group); //get the number of the group by removing everying in the string `$group` that is not a number (leaving just the number)

        $next_article_data = array();
        if(isset($laws[$group][$chapter][$article+1])){
             $next_article_data['group'] = $group;
             $next_article_data['chapter'] = $chapter;
             $next_article_data['article'] = $article+1;
        }else if(isset($laws[$group][$chapter+1][1])){
             $next_article_data['group'] = $group;
             $next_article_data['chapter'] = $chapter+1;
             $next_article_data['article'] = 1;
        else if (isset($laws["group".($group_num+1)][1][1])){
             $next_article_data['group'] = "group".($group_num+1);
             $next_article_data['chapter'] = 1;
             $next_article_data['article'] = 1;
        else
            echo "NO NEXT ARTICLE!";


        ?>

        <a href="process.php<?php 

        //I added this to pass article info in the url
        echo "?".http_build_query($next_article_data); 
        ?>" style="text-decoration: none;">NEXT ARTICLE</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given much to go on, but assuming that `$_GET['article']` is supposed to be an article number, you would just increment it by 1 (assuming that your articles are sequential):

```
<a href="process.php?article=<?php echo (int)$_GET['article'] + 1; ?>" style="text-decoration: none;">NEXT ARTICLE</a>
```